# Export products from Amazon onto Magento?

Tags: magmi, amazon-web-services, m2e

I was hoping someone could clue me in on how to import products into Magento from Amazon.

I understand you can download an csv from your Amazon seller account, has name, description, quantity, ASIN...

There are other plugins for Magento that if you enter the ASIN it will get everything, image, description, ect.

My question is, if I first import my CSV from Amazon (ASIN would then be in Magento), can I then use one of these extensions to pull in the rest of the info, and Magento match it both ASINs?

Comment: Look into M2EPro.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Magmi importer and as @seanbreeden suggested M2EPro.  One or the other and/or the combination will get the job done.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

http://m2epro.com/